# How to pass data to another component not in the URL with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'm trying to pass data to another component with React Router and TypeScript. I currently pass a slug in the url itself, but I also need to pass an id associated with it. I don't want the id in the path itself because it would leak information about my database. I have looked around and only found people accomplishing this by passing it in the path.

Here is the component with the Link. I would like to pass the `movie.id` value. I've omitted my fetch that places the movie data in movies.

```js
    export const MovieCards: React.FC = () => {
      const [movies, setMovies] = useState<Movie[]>([]);     
      return (
        <>
          {movies.map((movie) => (
            <div key={movie.id}>
              <img
                style={{ width: "300px" }}
                src={movie.picture_url}
                alt="movie poster"
              />
              <Link to={`/movie/${movie.slug}`}>{movie.title}</Link>
              <p>{movie.avg.toString().substr(0, 4)}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </>
      );
    };
```

Here is the component with the Router

```js
const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route path="/" exact>
        <IndexPage />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/movie/:slug">
        <MoviePage />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

And this is the component I need access to movie.id

```js
export const MoviePage: React.FC = () => {
  let { slug } = useParams();
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Movie page</div>
      <div>{slug}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: That's why Redux. Redux allows you to pass a universal state. REDUX will help you out quickly with this.

Comment: I wouldn't consider learning all of Redux as a quick solution. If there is a way to do this within React itself, that is more what I am looking for as a practical solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data through the `<Link>`. It can solve your problem of not sending data through the URL. You can pass as much data as you want in the object.

```
<Link to ={{
    pathname: {`/movie/${movie.slug}`}, 
    state: {  
        id: movie.id,  
    }
   }} >
 {movie.title}
</Link>
```

The movie id is passed now at the MoviePage Component.

```
  export const MoviePage: React.FC = ({  id
}: InferProps<typeof Article.propTypes>) ) => {

      let { slug } = useParams();
      const { id } = state;

      return (
        <div>
          <div>Movie page</div>
          <div>{slug}</div>
          <h1>Id of Movie is : {id}</h1>
        </div>
      );
    };
//Check the id type in type script
Article.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.number.isRequired
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Your [`Link`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) component is able to pass more than just a url.  You can use it to pass a complex state by setting the prop `to` as an `object` with a property `pathname` instead of the pathname as a `string`.

```js
    export const MovieCards: React.FC = () => {
      const [movies, setMovies] = useState<Movie[]>([]);     
      return (
        <>
          {movies.map((movie) => (
            <div key={movie.id}>
              <img
                style={{ width: "300px" }}
                src={movie.picture_url}
                alt="movie poster"
              />
              <Link to={{
                pathname: `/movie/${movie.slug}`,
                state: {
                  id: movie.id,
                  data: movie,
                }
              }}>{movie.title}</Link>
              <p>{movie.avg.toString().substr(0, 4)}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </>
      );
    };
```

In the linked-to component, the passed state becomes available as a property of `location`.  In order to get proper types for the passed state, you need to tell typescript what to expect by setting the generic on `useLocation`.

```js
interface PassedState {
  id: number;
  data: Movie;
}

export const MoviePage: React.FC = () => {
  const { slug } = useParams();
  const { state } = useLocation<PassedState>();
  const { id, data } = state;
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Movie page</div>
      <div>{slug}</div>
      <div>{id}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```